# Can I keep appending data to the cache in react-query?

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using React Query and trying to get the most out of the query cache.

In my case, I have a search endpoint which acts like `(searchString: string) => Client[]`, where the return is, of course, matching the search string. This is expected to change but I'll eventually end up with the Client I want. I may end up with other clients I'll want on later searches too.

I know I can create a `queryKey: ["clients", searchString]` that will cache the results in independent blocks but those would be difficult to search through. What I'd like to be able to do is `queryClient.getQueryData("clients")` the same way as i would get data from my list endpoint (`/clients`). Is that possible with a built-in API or do I have to do something like

```
queryClient.setQueryData("clients", (newData, oldData) => [...newData, ...oldData])
```

where I'm managing my cache manually?